# Dependent two select lists in Thymeleaf Bootstrap

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I want to do 2 selected lists.

In my controller I pass to template two lists from database and with using standard selected lists options I can see all correct values in both of them, in first I see names of departments in second names of institutes(all possible institutes).

```
<option th:each="dept : ${departments}" th:value="${dept.details.departmentFullName}" th:text="${dept.details.departmentFullName}"></option>
```

And same for institutes.
I want to do that in second selected list gets only institutes from selected department in first selected lists(by department id in institute table).

How can I do that in thymeleaf?

Comment: It is not the task for Thymeleaf. You have implement such logic in controller. Thymeleaf just shows the model composed by controller.

Comment: I did HashMap where key is object of Department and value is List of Institutes. But now I don't know how can I get keys and values in selected lists depends than key.